# Would having an area to publish non-questions be useful?

Tags: feature-request, blog

Would it be of value if the site would allow users to publish some of their non-question thoughts? For example, someone may stumble over a simple formula that think it is interesting to share. I guess the site would be nice place to post such topics as long as it is not in the Questions section. What do you think (pls don't be harsh)!

Comment: I hear that Wordpress is great.

Comment: You are correct, but having a blog for a single idea is not practical besides the fact that the number of people that may visit a not-famous blog would be very tiny.

Comment: You could always cheat/lie by posting your simple formula as a reference request. "Has anybody seen this before? I call it ... the quadratic formula!"

Comment: Good idea Gerry, let's keep that starting phrase a secret between us ;)

Answer (score 1):

We already have such an area: it's called chat.

Comment: +1, I never tried this, may be I should, thanks.